# Determining singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

has a singularity that is necessarily removable. I think that the answer is no, and I have tried to obtain an $f$ with a pole. But I am not sure how to interpret the importance of the 4/3 expression. Is this the right idea? Should I be looking for a function with an essential singularity, or in fact is the singularity necessarily removable? It was suggested that I start by showing that $f'$ has at most a simple pole, but I'm not sure how to use this suggestion. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(z) = z f'(z)$ in the the punctured disk. Then
$$
 |z g(z)| = |z^2 f'(z)| \le |z|^{2/3} \cdot \sup_{0<|z|<1}|z|^{4/3}|f'(z)|
$$
shows that $\lim_{z \to 0} z g(z) = 0$. So $g(z)$ has a removable singularity at the origin (Riemann's theorem).

Here are two different ways how one can continue and conclude that $f$ has a removable singularity at the origin:

**Variant A:** We have
$$
 f'(z) = \frac 1z g(z)
$$
where $g$ is holomorphic in the unit disk. It follows that $f'$ is holomorphic at the origin or has at most a simple pole.

But poles of derivatives have at least the multiplicity $2$. So $f'$ has a removable singularity at the origin, and so has $f$.

**Variant B:** Use the Laurent series  $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$:
$$
 g(z) = zf'(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n a_n z^n
$$
has a removable singularity at the origin, so that $a_n= 0$ for all $n < 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up questions: why is it impossible that 1/z*g has an essential singularity? Also, why does f' having a removable singularity imply that f does too? Here I can see that f couldn't have a pole, but why couldn't it have an essential singularity?

Comment: @Marble: If $f'$ has a removable singularity at the origin $f'$ it is bounded near the origin, which implies (e.g. by integration) that $f$ is also bound near the origin. You can also look at the Laurent series of $f$ to see that if $f$ has an essential singularity then $f'$ has an essential singularity as well.

Comment: Okay, and regarding (1/z)*g? Why couldn't the product have an essential singularity? Would this also be an appeal to the laurent series?

Comment: @Marble: $\frac 1z g(z) = \frac{g(0)}{z} + O(1)$ has a removable singularity or a pole depending on whether $g(0)$ is zero or not.